# What is the role of dot sign- sql-snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just start learning sql in snowflake. I encountered with an issue. Although I have looked through the internet, I could not find related comments. Would you please tell what is the role of "." sign and "d" in the following code:
While the col names are PATID, BIRTH_DATE, and SEX, I can not understand what is the role of "d."

```
create or replace table PIM as
select d.PATID,
       d.BIRTH_DATE,
       d.SEX,
```

Best

Comment: It's an aliased table name. Such as `select d.col1, d.col2 from table1 d join table2 m on d.col = m.col`. Makes it much easier to read/write sql when you are joining tables.

Comment: Yes. The rest of the code related to joining tables. Thank you. @Isolated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called table aliasing.

Most likely the rest of the SQL would look like this

```
create or replace table PIM as
select d.PATID,
       d.BIRTH_DATE,
       d.SEX,
       d.SOME_OTHER_COLUNM
  from MYTABLE d
```

It is used to identify same name columns when 2 or more tables used in Select

Comment: Yes. The res:  `from identifier($demograph) d 
join identifier($encoun) enc on d.patid = enc.patid`